# Regarding Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I created this class library(ReportLib) with a simple Telerik report using Telerik Reporting Wizard. I then made this simple web application project, added ReportLib as a reference. Now in my asp page, intellisense is not detecting Telerik:ReportViewer tag! In the code behind too I have added the following ;-

```
using Telerik.Reporting;
using Telerik.ReportViewer;
```

What's wrong ? My web app project is building successfully. Why won't it detect the telerik  tags?

[EDIT]

Do i need to register the Telerik.Reporting.dll on my aspx page too? How to do that ?

Registered assembly as follows..still wont detect the telerik:report viewer tag:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationReporting1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Reporting" Namespace="Telerik.Reporting" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer" Namespace="Telerik.ReportViewer" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
 <tel
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[EDIT]

ok in my web config file..there's no telerik assebly added that I can see..How so ? I did add the refernce to telerik reporting dll! Why didnt it show up in web config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Telerik Reporting documentation about your problem. First, you will need to create your [report within a class library project](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/quick-start-create-simple-report.html), and then assign the report to the [Web Report Viewer](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/asp-net-report-viewer-overview.html).

In case you still have problems, contact Telerik - they will assist you with a more detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your project most likely, does not have the correct reference to the correct Telerik assmbly. The contractors we sometimes hire where I work, run into this and 100% of the time thats been the issue.

If you dont know how to register the control then go into the design mode for your page and drag it from the toolbar, and drop it into your page. VS will write the code for you.

The drag-and-drop solution will also take care of your web.config settings